# Duplicate type name within an assembly

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am working with Effort and Entity Framework 4.1(code first). When I create fake databadse and try to add something

```
DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();

using (var context = new LoveDatabaseContext(connection))
{
    context.Banners.Add(new Banners() { Enabled = true, Name = "Test", Priority = 1, Url = "http:\\test.com" });
}
```

I am getting error: 
System.ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.

I clean solution rebuilt and it not worked for me

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328364/system-argumentexception-duplicate-type-name-within-an-assembly where a clean is only 1 of the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Duplicate type name within an assembly (6.1.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189266/entity-framework-duplicate-type-name-within-an-assembly-6-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

I have found this happens when debugging, put your breakpoint after the call to the database.

Comment: Boom, this was exactly it.