# Using Html.Action and PartialView but get a Duplicate type name within an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am using Html.Action and PartialView.

I have a linq statement that I know is working correctly.

However when trying to use the Html.Action I am getting a different result from the linq statement.

I am getting this error message

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

But the really error message is

> Duplicate type name within an assembly

I have checked my data, clean my solution and used the Linqer tool to make sure the statement is working correctly.  No luck.

Here's what I created.

**The html Code**

```
@model @model IEnumerable<MvcCureUrbanNonProfit.Models.PageContent>
@Html.Action("PageContentDisplay", "Home", new { id = 1 })
```

**For the PartialView**

```
@model MvcCureUrbanNonProfit.Models.PageContent
@Html.Raw(@Model.PageContentLongDesc)
```

**For the ActionResult method**

```
public ActionResult PageContentDisplay(int id)
{
  var pageContentList = from p in db.PageContents
                        from w in db.WebSites 
                        where w.WebSiteID == 4 && p.PageTab == 1 && p.PageContentSeqNbr = 1
                        select p;
  return PartialView("_PageContentDisplay", pageContentList);
}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be `from w in p.WebSites`?

Comment: Are you using Ef 6.1? If yes then check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189266/entity-framework-duplicate-type-name-within-an-assembly-6-1-0

Comment: I have another table called WebSitePageContents. This table does not exist in the entity framework.  I'm on Ef 6.0.  Should I update to Ef 6.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manager to figure out the issue with the error message.  After spending several hours trying to understand the error message it turns out that the problem had to do with having an anonymous type<\b>.

My linq query was returning an IQueryable.  I only needed 1 item from the collection. So I added ".First() to return the first element.

[ChildActionOnly]

public ActionResult PageContentDisplay(int id)
{

```
int webSiteNbr;
bool result = int.TryParse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebSite"], out webSiteNbr);
PageTab pageTab = PageTab.Home;
int pageTabVal = (int)pageTab;

var pagContentList2 = from p in db.PageContents
                      from w in db.WebSites
                      where w.WebSiteID == webSiteNbr && p.PageTab == pageTabVal && p.PageContentSeqNbr == id
                      //select p;
                      select new PageContentVM
                      {
                          PageContentID = p.PageContentID,
                          PageContentLongDesc = p.PageContentLongDesc
                      };

return PartialView("_PageContentDisplay", pagContentList2.Single());
```

}